# CMake Server: Docs mismatch, clarification needed

Tags: cmake

I was running across this piece of documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake-server.7.html

But as it turns out, the description given on how to start the server, is not the same as shown in the documentation. When executing `cmake -E server --debug`, I am getting the following message:

```
CMake Error: No protocol versions defined. Maybe you need --experimental?
```

When adding the suggested flag `--experimental`, the server will launch, reading from standard input and responding to standard output, as expected. However, all the examples shown on the documentation do not suggest the use of this flag. Plus, I have version `3.13.4` installed as well.

What is the proper way of starting the CMake server, as in how would I specify the protocol version, and why am I asked to use `--experimental`?

My main goal is to find out if I can extract values like targets and their associated information (like `CFLAGS`) off CMake. Using this server command would certainly let me do this by just writing a small piece of NodeJS code to interact with it.